# How to show the actual foreign key id in Django admin?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

When I'm in admin looking at a Bar record, the dropdown for the foreign key shows the title of Foo, and not the id of Foo. There can be multiple titles with the same name, so this is not helpful. **I would like to see the id of Foo while I'm looking at Bar in admin.**

Here's my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Foo(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Bar(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Herey's my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Foo, Bar


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('id',)


class BarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('id',)


admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
admin.site.register(Bar, BarAdmin)
```

Comment: Now you are getting **Foo object (1)** So you want to see only 1 in there--right?

Comment: The dropdown for the foreign key in the admin is populated with the title of the Foo record it's linked to. I want either that dropdown or some other field to show me the id of the Foo record it's linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your **model**.

```
 class Bar(models.Model):
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.id
```